# Auto tab when using Telerik Rad Controls

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, telerik

I am looking to auto tab from one RadNumericTextBox to the next once the MaxLength has been reached.

I can do this in classic ASP, but cannot figure it out in .Net.  Below is an example of my RadNumericTextBox.

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="RadNumericTextBox_ExpLocation" runat="server" Width="20px"
MaxLength="3" NumberFormat-AllowRounding="False" Type="Number" NumberFormat-KeepTrailingZerosOnFocus="True"
IncrementSettings-InterceptMouseWheel="false" >
<NumberFormat DecimalDigits="0" GroupSeparator="" AllowRounding="false" KeepNotRoundedValue="false" />
```

AHIA,
Larry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that control renders a regular textbox on the client then you might just use a jquery plugin to autotab the boxes.

http://www.mathachew.com/sandbox/jquery-autotab/